# Для чего использовать operator

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь понять смысл перегрузки операторов но никак не могу.

Есть код

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter
{
public:
    Counter(int sec)
    {
        seconds = sec;
    }
    void display()
    {
        std::cout << seconds << "<-SECONDS" << std::endl;
    }
    int seconds;
};
Counter operator + (Counter c1, Counter c2)
{
    return Counter(c1.seconds + c2.seconds);
}
void main()
{
    Counter c1(20);
    Counter c2(90);
    Counter c3 = c1 + c2;
    c3.display();
}
```

В этом коде у меня возникает вопрос для чего использовать оператор если можно в `main()`
Сделать `Counter c3 = c1.seconds + c2.seconds` и код будет прекрасно работать без перегрузки операторов.
Для чего тогда нужен оператор?

Comment: `std::string hi{"Hello"}; std::string world{"world"}; std::string omg = hi + ' ' + world;`

Comment: Конкретно в данном случаи для удобства .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

познакомьтесь с понятиями инкапсуляции и абстракции, потому что вызов оператора может чуть ли не ракету запускать, даже на простом примере вот, как просто сложить комплексные числа и вывести их с перегрузками, не заглядывая во внутреннюю реализацию:

```
#include <iostream>

class Complex
{
private:
  int x, y;
public:
  Complex(int x, int y) { this->x = x;this->y = y; }

  friend Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs) {
    return Complex(lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y);
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Complex& complex) {
    std::cout << complex.x << "+i" << complex.y;
    return out;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Complex a(1, 3);
  Complex b(2, 4);

  Complex c = a + b;
  std::cout << c;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Логика работы сложения объектов произвольных типов может быть много сложнее, чем просто сложить два члена. Так вот внутри оператора её и необходимо инкапсулировать. Чтобы используя объекты класса можно было просто писать **c3 = c1 + c2** и не задумываться о деталях.